# What does the "Co" in "CoClass" mean?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, com

I'm currently reading this text on COM:

[http://www.amazon.com/Essential-COM-Don-Box/dp/0201634465](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634465)

I'm up to the bit about COM Classes, also know as "CoClasses." I totally get what they are, what they do, and how they relate to interfaces.

But here's my question: what exactly does the "Co" in "CoClass" mean? Is it "Co" as in "cooperate," or "co" as in "concrete," or "co" as in "COM," or "co" as in something else entirely?

Comment: It's short for `COM`.

Comment: Its short for *Component Object* (as in COM)

Comment: I'd guess at System Hungarian, it was still big back when COM was engineered.  Some of the Hungarian prefixes can be pretty hard to reverse, but this one is fairly guessable.  Not quite gone, the WinRT versions are Ro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CO is for "Component Object". Check the official documentation for IDL here: [coclass attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366751(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The coclass statement provides a listing of the supported interfaces
> for a **component object**.

And an old article about COM here: [Understanding Interface Definition Language: A Developer's Survival Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20170917174503/http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0898/idl/idl.aspx)

> "The coclass statement is used to define a **component object** and the
> interfaces that it supports"